# Overload hasPermission in CustomPermissionEvaluator

Tags: java, overloading, spring-el

Im trying to overload the hasPermission-method in a PermissionEvaluator. But in the exception java cant find the method.

CustomPermissionEvaluator.java:

```
public class CustomPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator {

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Object targetDomainObject, Object permission) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Serializable targetId, String targetType,
            Object permission) {
            ...
    }

    // self overloading
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Object permission) {
        System.out.println("hasPermission with 1 variable");
        return true;
    }
}
```

The controller goes here:

```
@Service
public class UserController implements UsersApiDelegate {
    @Override
    @org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize("hasPermission('users.read')")
    public ResponseEntity<List<UserDto>> getUsers(Optional<String> acceptLanguage) {
        //...
    }
}
```

The errormessage ist:

```
ERROR 26800 --- [nio-8000-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression 'hasPermission('users.read')'] with root cause
```

Perhaps someone can help me.
I also tried:

```
@org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize("@CustomPermissionEvaluator .hasPermission('users.read')")
```

and

```
@org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize("@packages.to.the.class.CustomPermissionEvaluator.hasPermission('users.read')")
```

and

```
@org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize("packages.to.the.class.CustomPermissionEvaluator.hasPermission('users.read')")
```

But unfortunately nothing worked so far.

What am I missing?

Comment: I also tried with @Component('test') for the CustomPermissionEvaluator 
and @PreAuthorize("@test.CustomPermissionEvaluator.hasPermission('read')")

Answer (score 0):

could you check that way?

`@PreAuthorize("@packages.to.the.class.CustomPermissionEvaluator.hasPermission({ T(package.to.class.Users).READ} )")`

Comment: I tried now with @PreAuthorize("@packages.to.the.class.CustomPermissionEvaluator.hasPermission({users.read}), while users should remain a simple string.
But unfortunately it doesn't work